# Allow soft keyboard push a view up

Tags: android

I have an edit text, and a button below the edit text.

It is a fragment layout.

I want the keyboard to push up the button so it will always be visible on the screen.

**This is my layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:ems="10" >

    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for that
or android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Comment: State hidden means that the keyboard will always be hidden when the activity starts, and adjust pan is that the focused edittext will be visible.

But how do I make sure that the button is visible as well??

Comment: @user1940676 `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` will make button visible as well